# AngularJS getting JSON value to ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Im getting following json and want to repeat and bind the `value` but its seems something wrong.

**JSON**

```
{
    "1428394433116":[
        {
            "path":"path0","value":"test path 2"
        },
        {
            "path":"path1","value":"test path 1"
        }
    ],
    "1428467596813":[
        {
            "path":"path0","value":"path info 1"
        },
        {
            "path":"path1","value":"path info 2"
        },
        {
            "path":"path2","value":"path info 3"
        }
    ] }
```

**ng-repeater**

```
<p ng-repeat="p in ps">
    <label>Path <span ng-bind="$index"></span> :</label>
         <span class="normal-f">
              <span ng-bind="p.value"></span>
              <input type="text" ng-model="a.path[$index]">
         </span>
</p>
```

**Update**

Thanks, ID-1428394433116 for one module and ID-1428467596813 for another module.

So expected result is:

```
path 1: test path 2
path 2: test path 1
```

Comment: I guess you require to write ps.1428394433116 in your ng-repeat, because value is inside this "1428394433116". but it will give only value related to this not this "1428467596813".

Comment: please accept the answer if you get help from that, so that others can also get help.

Answer (score 1):

You try to bind an Array as String on this Line `<span ng-bind="p.value"></span>`

`p.value` does not exist, because `p` is an Array.
The first `p` shoud look like this:

```
[
    {
        "path":"path0","value":"test path 2"
    },
    {
        "path":"path1","value":"test path 1"
    }
]
```

You have to use another `ngRepeat` for `p` or you have to use the first Element everytime like this `<span ng-bind="p[0].value"></span>`

that means the best method shoud look like this:

```
<p ng-repeat="(ID, p) in ps"><!-- here you get the index (ID) and the Array (p) -->
    <label>Path <span ng-bind="ID"></span> :</label>
    <span ng-repeat="element in p track by $index" class="normal-f"><!-- here comes the other repeat -->
        <span ng-bind="element.value"></span>
        <input type="text" ng-model="a.path[$index]">
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, ID-1428394433116 for one module and ID-1428467596813 for another module.

So expected result is:
path 1: test path 2
path 2: test path 1

Answer (score 0):

Here the JSON data contains another JSON data.

So '1428394433116' contains one set of data or JSON and '1428467596813' contains another set of JSON. So you require to use ps.1428394433116 and ps.1428467596813 separately to get value.